# define list in header vertice on c++

Tags: c++, list, vertices

I have problem with define syntax of `List` this error that I getting, I tried creating a list of `Vertice` and I have problem with the syntax, I tried using namespace `STD` also in a header but still getting an error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::list> *" to "std::list>" graf    C:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Desktop\graf\graf\Vertice.cpp   39

[image]

**Vertice.h**

```
  #pragma once
  #include <list>
  #include <iostream>
  class Vertice {
  std::list<Vertice> getList();
  void setList(Vertice v);

  private:
    std::list<Vertice> *N;
   };
```

**Vertice.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vertice.h"

using namespace std;

Vertice::Vertice(int b, int f) {
  N = new list < Vertice > ();
  color = 0;
}

list < Vertice > Vertice::getList() {
  return  N;
}
void Vertice::setList(Vertice v) {
  this - > N - > push_front(v);
}
Vertice::~Vertice() {
  N - > clear();
}
```

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please copy-paste the errors (in full and complete) as *text*. And add comments in the shown source where you get the errors.

Comment: A hint though: In which namespace is the standard library `list` template defined?

Comment: Are you claiming that you get the same error message even if the `//using namespace std;` line is commented in? [I cannot reproduce that](https://godbolt.org/z/a3Dgfa). That being said, you should *not* use `using namespace std;` in the header. Instead write `std::list` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting comments and not answers is because you
a) Did not post the error message (as mentioned in a comment)
b) Your code contains many errors and some anti-patterns.

When using namespaces in C++ the convention is to use the full namespace in header

```
std::list<Vertice> *N; // member declaration
```

and a "using" declaration in the module.

```
using namespace std;
...
list<Vertice> Vertice::getList() const // return by value, mark as const
{
    return N; // you don't need this->N in C++ 
}
```

However, many people prefer to simply type the full namespace always, so if you find this easier to understand, try using that.

What are you trying to achieve with this code? The reason I ask is because dynamically allocating a "std::list" is a bit weird. A "std::list" is designed to manage memory for you, which makes this code read a bit like "allocate a pointer to hold the address of the memory I'm about to allocate". I strongly suspect you are trying to make a recursive structure (a tree). Surprisingly C++ does not require you to use pointers to do this (C does). Maybe this pattern will help?

```
class NTree
{
private:
  std::list<NTree> children;
};
```

I would suggest you get your code working like that first. If need to optimize, you will more control of the memory, then something like this will help.

```
class NTree
{
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NTree>> children;
};
```

This will allow you to, for example, move a child from one node (NTree) to another (NTree - or other), in a safe way. This avoids any copying overhead. This is a minor saving unless either your trees get very big or they contain objects which are very big. Even expert C++ programmers will try and get their code working before trying an optimization like this. There is no way to predict if it will required or not, so as always benchmark before and after.

Comment: i tried to change , and now i getting this error  "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0415 no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::list<Vertice, std::allocator<Vertice>> *" to "std::list<Vertice, std::allocator<Vertice>>" graf C:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Desktop\graf\graf\Vertice.cpp 39 
"  i update above with picture

Comment: Your problem is that you still have a pointer in your structure.

Comment: I'd suggest use `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` is kind of meaningless here afaict.

Comment: but i can fixed this

Comment: @appleapple: Shared pointers are for sharing. Moving from one structure to another is not sharing it's moving and unique_ptr supports moving. see https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f26-use-a-unique_ptrt-to-transfer-ownership-where-a-pointer-is-needed

Comment: @Tiger4Hire you can as simple move out the whole `NTree`. I mean, use `unique_ptr` adds almost nothing to the existing code. (unless you're planing to leave holes in the children list, even though I highly suspect you would as well need to use `shared_ptr` (and `week_ptr`) at that situation)

Comment: @appleapple: I was hinting that maybe you might want to move a branch of the tree to a new location (without copying). A unique_ptr allows you to that in a safe way. shared_ptr allows you to do it as well, but with more overhead and no gain. May be I will edit the answer to make that clearer. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Sorry, I kind of lost them, what I need is a list, why I need to change a lot of things in the code, maybe can you show example how can fixed this issue?

Comment: @Tiger4Hire well, `std::vector` support `std::move`, and the `NTree` 'd probably also get a default one. (If you mean the address of `NTree` should not change... well, I'd still suggest use `shared_ptr` since you're actually sharing) (If you mean the `NTree` is somehow not copyable or very expensive to copy. You have a valid point, then)

Comment: so i need to change to vector insted of List?

Comment: @danielshmu shmayovich : The example is in the answer. You might want to find every "*" in your header/module file and delete it. I can see one in Vertice.h:line 25 for example

Comment: @danielshmu shmayovich: No, I would develop with a list (and no pointers) first. This is the easy way to solve your problem. However the advanced way is to use a vector of pointers. I would not advise this for you.

Comment: @Tiger4Hire , but if i remove this "*" , getting this error [link](https://imghostr.com/NM2tLcsAZ)

Comment: problem on constructor , i want to create new list to put on N